# Corollary of Bolzano's theorem (i.e. IVT)

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Let $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function, such that $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)=-\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to b^-}f(x)=\infty$. Then there exists $c\in (a,b)$ such that $f(c)=0$.

Proof: Due to one-sided limits, there exists $\delta_1>0$ such that $f(x)<-1$ for all $x\in (a,a+\delta_1)$, and there exists $\delta_2>0$ such that $f(x)>1$ for all $x\in (b-\delta_2,b)$. Is there a way to choose $a'\in (a,a+\delta_1)$ and $b'\in (b-\delta_2,b)$ such that $a'<b'$? If I draw a line with these numbers, I expect it should look like

$-|--|-------|--------|------|-----|--$

$\;$ $a$$\hspace{0.8cm}$       $a'$ $\hspace{2cm}$ $a+\delta_1$$\hspace{2.5cm}$ $b-\delta_2$$\hspace{2cm}$$b'$$\hspace{2.2cm}$$b$

However, to make it happen, I need $\delta_1,\delta_2$ to satisfy $a+\delta_1<b-\delta_2$. I imagined, I should take an $\delta$ in terms of $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ (perhaps, the smallest of them?), so that we would get $a+\delta<b-\delta$, or that $a'<b'$, but do not know if it still would be true. Why do I care? So that I could conclude that $f$ is continuous in $[a',b']$ and $f(a')f(b')<0$, then the existence of root of $f$ will follow by [Bolzano's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem).

Comment: Just take (e.g.) $a' := \min(a+(b-a)/3, a+\delta_1/2)$ and likewise for $b'$.

Comment: The $\delta_1$ exists. Then define $\Delta_1=\min(\delta_1, (b-a)/3)$. After that, picking *any* $a' \in (a,a+\Delta_1)$ should work

Comment: As for your approach, you can just replace both $\delta_i$ by $min(\delta_i, (b-a)/3)$ or something similar.

Comment: @311411 With your method, I should pick any $b'\in (b-\Delta_2,b)$, where $\Delta_2=\min \{\delta_2,(b-a)/3\}$. Is there an easier way to confirm that $a'<b'$ without checking cases for minimality of $\Delta_i$?

Comment: It is cleaner to just take min of all three positive numbers. See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\Delta \,:=\, \min\left(\delta_1,\,\delta_2,\,\frac{b-a}3\right).$$

Now pick any $a' \,\in\, (a,a+\Delta),$ and pick any $b' \,\in\, (b-\Delta,b)$.

Confirmation that $a'<b':$

$$a' \,<\, a+\Delta \,<\, a+\frac{b-a}{2} \,=\, b-\frac{b-a}{2} \,<\, b-\Delta \,<\, b'.$$

Checking that $\Delta < (b-a)/2,$ using that $b-a$ is greater than zero:

$$\Delta \,=\, \min\left(\delta_1,\,\delta_2,\,\frac{b-a}3\right)\,\leqslant\, \frac{1}3\cdot (b-a)\,<\, \frac{1}2\cdot (b-a).$$

Comment: Yeah, it looks like I have been missing the part of $(b-a)/3$ when I tried to fix my problem. How did you come with this idea? Bascially, I would have thinking of the midpoint, but you chose looking at the one third of the distance between the endpoints instead

Comment: I have seen professors do this many times in lecture, and the approach was loaded into my brain :)

Comment: Yeah I noticed it as well in various proofs, though I never understood how they came with this idea, when it eventually worked, hence my question. Can I ask, why $\Delta < (b-a)/2$ is valid? Did you simply say that if $\Delta=\delta_1$, then it would be less than or equal to either $\delta_2$ or $(b-a)/3$. Since $\delta_2$ is small, it could be smaller than $(b-a)/3$ or greater than $(b-a)/3$, but it does not matter as long as we need a number that is greater than $\delta_1$. Since $(b-a)/3<(b-a)/2$, we conclude that $\Delta=\delta_1<(b-a)/2$. Similar for other cases. Is my understanding good?

Comment: We do not know if $\Delta = \delta_1.$ But in any case $\Delta \leq \delta_1.$

Comment: I know, it was just an assumption, where I thought about proving it by three cases. But it seems clear now after you have edited your answer. Thanks for your help and your time!

Comment: you are welcome. Until next time, cheers